# Calculate min and average excluding negative in Excel Pivot

Tags: excel, pivot-table, average, minimum

I have a database with names and their related values in positive and negatives.
When applying Pivot Table format to the data, the maximum appears nicely however minimum includes the negative value and so does the average value.

Could you please suggest what other formula should i apply within the Pivot to exclude negatives when calculating minimum and average.

Thanks in advance.